# Parcelable Bitmap with the intention of uploading the bitmap

Tags: java, android, image, stream

I could really use another set of eyes on this. No one else in the office has a lot of experience working with Android, so I'm on my own with this one.

The goal of this class is to encapsulate an image which can be sourced from a camera or file so that it can be uploaded to one of our servers using a POST request. Just looking at the code, it feels overly-complicated, and I'm afraid that this is super inefficient.

```
package com.package.android;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.package.R;

class UploadableImage implements Parcelable {
    public static final String UPLOADABLE_IMAGE = "UPLOADABLE_IMAGE";
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<UploadableImage> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<UploadableImage>() {
        public UploadableImage createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new UploadableImage(in);
        }

        public UploadableImage[] newArray(int size) {
            return new UploadableImage[size];
        }
    };
    private static final String JPEG_FILE_PREFIX = "IMG_";
    private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";
    private final String TAG = "UploadableImage";
    private File file;
    private String filepath;
    private Uri uri;
    private Bitmap bmp;
    private Context context;
    private AlbumStorageDirFactory mAlbumStorageDirFactory = null;
    private int fileSize;
    private String descriptionText;
    private String nameText;
    private String emailText;

    public UploadableImage(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        file = null;
        filepath = null;
        uri = null;
        bmp = null;
        fileSize = -1;
        descriptionText = null;
        nameText = null;
        emailText = null;
        setupStorageDirFactory();
    }


    public UploadableImage(Parcel in) {
        readFromParcel(in);
        setupStorageDirFactory();
    }

    static String filePathFromUri(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if (uri == null) {
            return null;
        }
        //see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16511111/940217
        String filepath = null;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
        Context ctx = context.getApplicationContext();
        if (ctx != null) {
            Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                // Here you will get a NPE if cursor is null.
                // This can be if you used OI File Manager (or other 3rd party) for picking the media
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                filepath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
            }
        } else {
            filepath = uri.getPath();               // For OI/Astro/Dropbox, etc.
        }
        return filepath;
    }

    private void setupStorageDirFactory() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory();
        } else {
            mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new BaseAlbumDirFactory();
        }
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean valid() {
        return (context != null && this.getFilepath() != null);
    }

    Uri getUri() {
        if (this.uri != null) {
            return this.uri;
        }

        if (this.file != null) {
            this.uri = Uri.fromFile(this.file);
            return this.uri;
        }

        if (this.bmp == null || context == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (this.filepath != null) {
            this.uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(this.filepath));
            return this.uri;
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        this.bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        Context ctx = context.getApplicationContext();
        if (ctx == null) {
            return uri;
        }
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(ctx.getContentResolver(), this.bmp, "Title", null);
        this.uri = Uri.parse(path);
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(Uri uri) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Setting URI to " + uri.toString());
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    private void setBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) {
        Uri tempUri = uri;
        Bitmap tempBmp = null;
        if (this.uri != null && uri == null) {
            tempUri = this.uri;
        }

        try {
            tempBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), tempUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: tried getting the bitmap from the MediaStore using the URI and failed. The URI given was: " + tempUri.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.bmp = tempBmp;
    }

    public File createFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
        File albumF = getAlbumDir();
        this.file = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
        return this.file;
    }

    public boolean deleteFile() {
        return this.file.delete();
    }

    /* Photo album for this application */
    private String getAlbumName() {
        return context.getString(R.string.album_name);
    }

    private File getAlbumDir() {
        File storageDir = null;
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            storageDir = mAlbumStorageDirFactory.getAlbumStorageDir(getAlbumName());
            if (storageDir != null) {
                if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "failed to create directory");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
        }
        return storageDir;
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
        this.filepath = this.file.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    public Bitmap getBmp() {
        if (this.bmp != null) {
            return this.bmp;
        }
        Bitmap resultBitmap = null;
        Uri tempUri = this.getUri();
        if (tempUri != null) {
            setBitmapFromUri(tempUri);
        }
        if (this.bmp != null) {
            resultBitmap = this.bmp;
        }
        this.bmp = resultBitmap;
        return resultBitmap;
    }

    public void setBmp(Bitmap bmp) {
        this.bmp = bmp;
    }

    private byte[] getBmpAsByteArray(Bitmap data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return null;
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        data.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    private void setBitmapFromByteArray(byte[] data) {
        this.bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    }

    public void updateFilepath() {
        if (this.uri != null) {
            setFilepath(filePathFromUri(this.context, uri));
        }
        getFilepath(null);
    }

    void invalidate() {
        if (getFileSize() == 0) {
            deleteFile();
        }
        file = null;
        bmp = null;
        filepath = null;
        fileSize = -1;
        uri = null;
    }

    String getFilepath() {
        return getFilepath(null);
    }

    public void setFilepath(String filepath) {
        this.filepath = filepath;
    }

    String getFilepath(Uri uri) {
        if (this.filepath != null) {
            return this.filepath;
        }
        if (this.file != null) {
            return this.file.getAbsolutePath();
        }

        if (uri == null) {
            uri = getUri();
        }

        return filePathFromUri(this.context, uri);
    }

    public Bitmap getScaledBitmap(int width, int height) {
        Bitmap scaledBmp = null;
        InputStream is;

        Bitmap oBmp = this.getBmp();
        if (oBmp != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "scaled bitmap was able to use a bitmap");
            return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(oBmp, width, height, false);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "scaled bitmap was not able to use a bitmap and will try to get it from a stream.");
        try {
            is = getInputStream();
            /* Get the size of the image */
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, bmOptions);
            int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
            int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;
            is.close();

            is = getInputStream();

            /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
            int scaleFactor = 1;
            if ((width > 0) || (height > 0)) {
                scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / width, photoH / height);
            }

            /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
            bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

            /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
            scaledBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, bmOptions);
            is.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not resize the bitmap - File Not Found Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IO Exception while trying to resize the bitmap");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return scaledBmp;
    }

    protected int sizeOf(Bitmap data) {
        /*
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            return data.getAllocationByteCount();
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
            return data.getRowBytes() * data.getHeight();
        } else {
            return data.getByteCount();
        }
        // NONE OF THE ABOVE RETURN ACCURATE RESULTS!
        // A Bitmap, when stored as a file takes up more room because it represents
        // full pixel data and is not compressed on disk.
        */
        byte[] bitmapdata = getBmpAsByteArray(data);
        return (bitmapdata == null) ? 0 : bitmapdata.length;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        InputStream is = null;
        Bitmap bmp = this.getBmp();
        if (this.file == null || this.bmp == null) {
            loadResources();
        }

        if (bmp != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "getting input stream from bitmap");
            byte[] bitmapdata = getBmpAsByteArray(bmp);
            this.fileSize = bitmapdata.length;
            is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "getting input stream from file");
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(this.file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "could not get an input stream from file with path: " + getFilepath());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return is;
    }

    private void loadResources() {
        Uri tempUri = getUri();
        if (tempUri != null) {
            this.file = new File(tempUri.getPath());
        }
        try {
            this.bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), tempUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException when trying to load the bitmap from URI: " + tempUri);
        }
    }

    public long getFileSize() {
        if (this.fileSize != -1) {
            return this.fileSize;
        }
        this.fileSize = sizeOf(getBmp());
        return this.fileSize;
    }

    public String getDescriptionText() {
        return descriptionText;
    }

    public void setDescriptionText(String descriptionText) {
        this.descriptionText = descriptionText;
    }

    public String getNameText() {
        return nameText;
    }

    public void setNameText(String nameText) {
        this.nameText = nameText;
    }

    public String getEmailText() {
        return emailText;
    }

    public void setEmailText(String emailText) {
        this.emailText = emailText;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(filepath);
        dest.writeString(uri.toString());
        dest.writeInt(fileSize);
        if (fileSize >= 0) {
            dest.writeByteArray(getBmpAsByteArray(getBmp()));
        }
        dest.writeString(descriptionText);
        dest.writeString(nameText);
        dest.writeString(emailText);
    }

    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        file = null;
        filepath = in.readString();
        uri = Uri.parse(in.readString());

        fileSize = in.readInt();
        if (fileSize >= 0) {
            byte[] bmpData = new byte[fileSize];
            in.readByteArray(bmpData);
            setBitmapFromByteArray(bmpData);
        }

        descriptionText = in.readString();
        nameText = in.readString();
        emailText = in.readString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
static String filePathFromUri(Context context, Uri uri) {
Uri getUri() {
void invalidate() {
String getFilepath(Uri uri) {
```

Missing access modifier. Is that intentional?

```
        if (cursor != null) {
            // Here you will get a NPE if cursor is null.
            // This can be if you used OI File Manager (or other 3rd party) for picking the media
```

But you just did an explicit check for `null`! Did I miss something, or is this comment contradicting the code? Comments that contradict the code represent a conflict, and conflicts should be resolved. Never just delete the comment; carefully check whether the code or the comment is right.

```
    Bitmap scaledBmp = null;
    InputStream is;

    Bitmap oBmp = this.getBmp();
    if (oBmp != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "scaled bitmap was able to use a bitmap");
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(oBmp, width, height, false);
    }
```

Don't declare variables if you don't need them. Move the declarations of `scaledBmp` and `is` below that if statement. Try to keep all your variable declarations close to where you need them.

---

A lot of your methods have side effects. I recommend adding javadoc comment blocks to list these side effects, or to rename them to explain that they have side effects. For instance:

```
private void setBitmapFromUri(Uri uri)
```

This method sets the bitmap to a bitmap pointed to by the supplied `Uri`... or, in the event no `Uri` is supplied, it sets the bitmap based on the current `Uri`! That's undocumented behavior.